# GMail Add a picture direct into the eMail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, email-attachments

about this script I can attach a picture to the eMail:

```js
function myTesteMail() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1DyNggP_DAZEO32kSdQTZFiEYG1bPCP3o');
  MailApp.sendEmail('xxxxxx@yyyyyy.com', 'Attachment example', 'my own test.', {name: 'my Script', attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.JPEG)]});
}
```

How I can add the picutre direct in the eMail?

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand, you want to embed the picture in the e-mail in-line, right? Look at the `inlineImages` option for `MailApp.sendEmail` (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a picture straight in the eMail by using the `htmlBody` parameter in `MailApp.sendMail`. You can see the [documentation for `MailApp` here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage).

```
function myTesteMail(){

    var email = 'user@domain.ext';
    var subject = 'Subject Test';
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "", { 
      htmlBody: " <html>\
        <body> Look at this email body \
        <img src='https://www.domain.ext/image.jpg' border='0' alt='error' 
          align='middle'></th>\
        </body>\
        </html>"
    });
}
```

Comment: I have also use dataURI's to load images into emails.  But I've only tested the email on web based email servers.

Comment: GMail doesn't support data URIs to be loaded so you'd have to convert them into a file resource first

Comment: I went back and tried sending my self an email via my internet service provider email and sure enough they display it on their email but Gmail evidently doesn't support it.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Hello, I understood - I can solve only about when I add the URL in the body. Thanks for you help. Greetings